# ContentPresenter of extended Window class not showing content at design-time

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, dependency-properties, contentpresenter

I am currently writing a Dialog class (lookless control) which extends Window, and am assigning a default ControlTemplate to that class using a XAML style.

I want the 'Buttons' section of my Dialog template to be replacable, yet pre-populate it with a set of default buttons if nothing else is specified. This is why I added a **dependency property** called `ButtonContent` to my class.

The `DefaultButtons` (see XAML below) are **rendered correctly when I run the application**, but **Visual Studio 2010's design preview does not render the content**. Why is this not happening?

My dialog class looks like this:

```cs
public class Dialog : Window
{
    public FrameworkElement ButtonContent
    {
        get { return (FrameworkElement)GetValue(ButtonContentProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ButtonContentProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ButtonContentProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ButtonContent", typeof(FrameworkElement), typeof(Dialog), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));

    static Dialog()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(Dialog), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(Dialog)));
    }
}
```

This is my XAML:

```xml
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Dialogs:Dialog}">
    <Setter Property="DataContext" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>     
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Dialogs:Dialog}">
                <StackPanel>
                    <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding ButtonContent}"/>
                    <TextBlock>This text is rendered correctly</TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>

    <Setter Property="ButtonContent">
        <Setter.Value>
            <!-- This stuff here is not shown in VS2010's preview -->
            <UniformGrid Name="DefaultButtons" Rows="1" Columns="2">
                <Button>Button 1</Button>
                <Button>Button 2</Button>
            </UniformGrid>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

When I launch the app, it looks like this:

[image: As rendered by the app]

The VS2010 designer renders this:

[image: As rendered by VS2010]

---

**Edit:** As described in the comments, placing the above style in Themes\Generic.xaml instead of my resource dictionary included from App.xaml does not change anything.

---

**Edit 2:** If I explicitly override the default `ButtonContent` like this, the designer also does not show anything. At runtime, everything works perfectly:

```xml
<Dialogs:Dialog x:Class="Dialogs.TestDialog"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:Dialogs="clr-namespace:Dialogs">
    <Dialogs:Dialog.ButtonContent>
        <Button>Also not shown at design time</Button>
    </Dialogs:Dialog.ButtonContent>
</Dialogs:Dialog>
```

---

**Edit 3:** If I add the `ButtonContent` property to a `UserControl` instead of my `Dialog` class that extends `Window`, the `ButtonContent` is displayed correctly within the user control... also, VS2010 seems to apply the style defined above to *any* window, not just those of class `Dialog`, although I have set the TargetType appropriately... weird!

Comment: When you say "this is my xaml" do you mean the generic.xaml? A Default style should usually be placed there.

Comment: The designer doesn't render code, only XAML.

Comment: @dowhilefor: I placed it in a separate XAML that was included in a MergedDictionary within my App.xaml. I also tried putting the default dialog style in Generic.xaml as you suggested. This did not change anything at runtime; at design time, however, that style was apparently not being applied at all, so this is even worse than my previous approach.

Comment: @Bob: But apparently, the designer does support this for the controls shipped with WPF by default (such as a ContentControl or a HeaderContentControl). Otherwise, the designer wouldn't render the content of a button or the header of tab items. Also, I do not really have much code – except for the static declaration of the dependency property!?

Comment: _Otherwise, the designer wouldn't render the content of a button or the header of tab items._ Your picture only shows the TextBlock rendered in VS Designer. Runtime is different than what shows in the Designer.

Comment: What I am saying is that there must be a way of making the missing content to show up, as other WPF controls manage to do this. Take the GroupBox, for example (a specialization of HeaderedContentControl): It allows me to set both its Content, and the Header (=dependency property), and both immediately show up in the designer.

Comment: As documented above, it seems to make a difference whether I do all this in a custom class that extends `Window`, or in a `UserControl`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I opened up a [bug report](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/770067/wpf-designer-not-sho) at Microsoft Connect for this issue. According to MS, it is a known issue and is by design:

> Thanks for reporting this issue. This is a known issue on our end and is by design. We cannot create a design instance of Window within the designer so we substitute with a proxy type of our own. That is the reason why it works correctly in a UserControl and not in a window. The workaround is to design the content of the dialog separately as a UserControl.